# AWS WebSocket Connection Time Limit - Other options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am creating a panic button app that requires clients to remain connected for several hours in case there is a panic alert triggered. AWS WebSockets disconnect after 2 hours, which defeats the purpose of my app.

I talked to AWS and they confirmed that there is no way to extend that. I need to find an alternative. What is the best way to keep clients connected for a long time? I have computers that need to remain connected sometimes for up to 8 or 10 hours and they can't disconnect because if they do and there is a panic alert triggered, they would not get it.

I wanted to go serverless, but I do not know if it is possible given the limitation of websockets disconnecting after 2 hrs. I did some research and people mentioned that I should use ELB and EC2. Would I be able to deploy a Socket.io app this way? If not socket.io, are there any other options?  How expensive can it get to keep clients connected to an EC2 instance with socket.io installed on it?

Comment: little bit late to the party. What was your solution? I'm in a similar situation

Comment: I deployed my app to Elastic Beanstalk and used Socket.io